# Can you see custom properties in Java Scene Builder with Custom Controls?

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

If I make a custom control with a Skin, Control and Behavior class, is it possible to show my custom properties in Java Scene Builder? If someone has already done this could you please explain how? I have but properties in both the Skin and Control sub classes without success.

Thanks

Jec

Edit 1:

So others can follow along, here is a sample 'Control' class which Scene Builder was able to detect.

```
public class DisplayControl extends Control
```

{
    private ObjectProperty m_BackgroundColor;

```
public DisplayControl()
{
    m_Skin = new DisplaySkin(this);


    m_BackgroundColor = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(new Color(0.5,
                                                             0.5,
                                                             0.5,
                                                             1));

    setSkin(m_Skin);
}


public ObjectProperty<Color> backgroundColor()
{
    return m_BackgroundColor;
}


/**
 * @return the m_BackgroundColor
 */
public Color getBackgroundColor()
{
    return m_BackgroundColor.get();
}


/**
 * @param BackgroundColor the BackgroundColor to set
 */
public void setBackgroundColor(Color backgroundColor)
{
    if (backgroundColor != m_BackgroundColor.get())
    {
        m_BackgroundColor.set(backgroundColor);
        m_Skin.setBackgroundColor(backgroundColor);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Ok I think I have this partially figured out. So you need to have the property in the 'Control' class. Make sure the 'Control' class's jar is built then imported into the Scene Builder. Then after you place the 'Control' it's properties will be listed under 'Custom' in the Properties window. In my case its a color and the field is still not editable so I'm still working on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your property accessor methods follow the [standard naming pattern](http://www.oracle.com/pls/topic/lookup?ctx=javase80&id=JFXBD107). You should have

```
public class DisplayControl extends Control {

// ...

    public ObjectProperty<Color> backgroundColorProperty() { ... }
    public Color getBackgroundColor() { ... }
    public void setBackgroundColor(...) { ...}
}
```

Comment: That worked. I still can't edit colors directly in SceneBuilder but at least its there. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you make use of javafx.scene.paint.Paint rather than Color, the value will be editable in Scene Builder

```
public class DisplayControl extends Control {

    // ...

    public ObjectProperty<Paint> backgroundColorProperty() { ... }
    public final Paint getBackgroundColor() { ... }
    public final void setBackgroundColor(final Paint color) { ...}
}
```